# how to solve the conflict of "column not found" on symfony 1.4 using doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

Sorry for this very specific question, Ive got this problem couple of times, and my solution (not the best was rename tables and do more stuffs), obviously its not a real solution, this time i got into same situation again, with a table I am not even manipulating, I wonder if someone got the same problem before.

Working with symfony 1.4 and doctrine, I get this error from a query of a not related table

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.training_id' in 'field list'
```

I really have no idea whats wrong, at my schema.yml i have something like this

```
OhrmTraining:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: training
  columns:
    id_training:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(60)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
TrainingDetail:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: training_detail
  columns:
    id_training_detail:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    training:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
   relations:
    OhrmTraining:
    local: training
    foreign: id_training
    type: one
```

Its related with other table Detail

like this

```
TrainingDetail:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: training_detail
  columns:
    id_training_deetail:
    type: integer(4)
    fixed: false
    unsigned: false
    primary: true
    autoincrement: true
  training:
    type: integer(4)
    fixed: false
    unsigned: false
    primary: false
    notnull: true
    autoincrement: false
relations:
  Training:
  local: training
  foreign: id_training
  type: one
```

Which I think its correct, but at my doctrine/base/BaseTraining.class I have something like this at the end (for training)

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasMany('TrainingDetail', array(
         'local' => 'id', <--- this should be the id_training_detail??
         'foreign' => 'training_id')); <--- this should be training?
```

I dont know why they are like that, or if they should be like that... could anybody help me with this?

I changed them for

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasMany('TrainingDetail', array(
         'local' => 'id_training',
         'foreign' => 'training'));
```

Still, I get the error, and if I make a remake models all will be gone

There is no easy way to create the schema.yml file from a DB?

EDIT:
the query that throws the exception is this

```
 $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Times a')
    ->where('a.employee_id = ?', $employeeId)
    ->orderBy('a.start_date ASC');
    $results = $query->execute();
```

I checked on the base of employee, and it has no relation with training, it has with training details... but not directly with training, i recreated my models 10 times and still the same

Comment: I don't think I can begin to make sense of your schema, as your terms are quite confusing.  That said, you are spelling `training` as `trainning` in several places.   That said, in your relation, you are defining `local: training`, except the field is named `trainning`.  There are probably other errors too.

Comment: sorry, the real name is not training, its CompanySomethingTrainning, but I changed it for the this case

Comment: Double check the spellings and the indentations of the whole schema file. If the indentations are wrong Doctrine might get confused.

Comment: I checked them, they seemed to be working fine, I tried removing them all, but nothing, another thing is that the table "Times" is not mentioned at my schema.yml, should I declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Still, I get the error, and if I make a remake models all will be gone"

This is because you edited the setup via a base class, base classes **ALWAYS** get overidden when you build models.

"There is no easy way to create the schema.yml file from a DB?"

This doesn't make sense. It's obvious you were able to generate a schema file from the schema, otherwise you wouldn't have a schema file.

The location of the relations appears correct according to the given schema file. According to [Doctrine's docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/yaml-schema-files.html):

"When specifying relationships it is only necessary to specify the relationship on the end where the foreign key exists. When the schema file is parsed, it reflects the relationship and builds the opposite end automatically. If you specify the other end of the relationship manually, the auto generation will have no effect."

When you build the model files, doctrine will correctly configure the `setUp` method in the base classes, so you don't need to do it. If you want to change the relationship, change it via the schema file then rebuild the model files.

I suspect the problem you are having is in how you are constructing the query, either via DQL or model references, due to the error you posted:

"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.training_id' in 'field list'"

**-- Edit --**

Based on the error, and your query, you could specify the columns to select, try this:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from('Times a')
    ->where('a.employee_id = ?', $employeeId)
    ->orderBy('a.start_date ASC');

$results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately no, the query is a simple select * from another table, not even related, thats why this error is so weird. I have no idea what to do right now, I dont know where that data is coming from!

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post, could you please take a look? I posted my query there.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, unfortunately when I try your query I get another error,  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object... Do I need to run something to fix this? or implement something? thanks for your help

Comment: The only time I have seen that error is when I misnamed an alias in a DQL construct. In the query you gave, it doesn't look like this is the case, you could try rebuilding your models, forms, and filters, then clearing cache and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Mike for the help, I made it work, but I had to change some stuffs at my base class on the doctrine folder, the problem is that its only a temporal solution :s due if i remake the models all cahnges will be gone :s

Comment: Ya, not a good permanent solution, I highly suggest you fix it either at the config level, or very least override the base classes.

Comment: but, isnt the schema.yml the base from where symfony create the base of the tables and so on?

Comment: Correct, but it is also used to generate the model files, more specifically the base model files. So as you mentioned, if you have custom changes in a base class, and rebuild the model, your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: yes, but... why all changes on the schema.yml are not being reflected on my base class? :s its confusing for me.

Comment: Are you doing a `php symfony doctrine:build-model` after changing the schema file? Maybe the files are version controlled and only have read access until you "check them out".

Comment: yes, I am running php symfony doctrine:build-model and that certainly ruines my base, but it doesnt set the relations like it is supposed to.. I dont know why

Comment: Not to sound "jerkish", but re-read my answer. Chances are you need to read up on how to properly establish FK relationships using the doctrine yaml markup. Taking some time now to learn how to do it will pay off big time down the road.